# cloning template Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I have a rather long complicated form to be used to record field data. One section of the form requires the ability to add a "Field Blank" section with no data recorded AND the ability to add a duplicate section where everything (including the data from the field blank section) is duplicated. The only different thing that would change on the duplicate would be the SampleID

The field blank script

```
 <script>

 var counter = 0;

 function moreFields() {
counter++;
var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
newFields.id = '';
newFields.style.display = 'block';
var newField = newFields.childNodes;
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
    var theName = newField[i].name
    if (theName)
        newField[i].name = theName + counter;
}
var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
 }


 </script>
```

The duplicate script

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var template_index=0;
  $("#add_FieldDup").click(function(){
    template_index++;
    $(this).parent().before($("#template").clone().attr("id","template" + template_index));
    $("#template" + template_index).css("display","inline");
    $("#template" + template_index + " :input").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("name",$(this).attr("name") + template_index);
        $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("id") + template_index);
        });
    $("#remove_Dup" + template_index).click(function(){
        $(this).closest("fieldset").remove();
    });
  }); 
 });
 </script>
```

My form

```
      <h3>Water Samples</h3>
      <fieldset id="template"> <!--for the duplicate-->
          <div id="template">  <!--for the duplicate-->

 Sample ID: <input type="text" id="SampleID" name="SampleID"></div>
 <div class="_40" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
  <label> Collection Method</label><br />
         <input type="radio" id="radGrab" value="grab" name="Collection" />
      <label for="radGrab">Grab</label>
          <input type="radio" id="radEWI" value="EWI" name="Collection" />
      <label for="radEWI">EWI</label>
            </div>

    <fieldset>     <!--For the field blank-->
  <div id="readroot" class="hidden"> <!--For the field blank-->
  QA Sample ID:<input type="text" id="QASampleID" name="QASampleID">
 <div class="_30" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true" data-type="horizontal">
 <label>Collection Method</label><br />
         <input type="radio" id="radGrab1" value="Grab" name="Collection1" />
      <label for="radGrab1">Grab</label>
          <input type="radio" id="radEWI1" value="EWI" name="Collection1" />
      <label for="radEWI1">EWI</label></div>
  </div>

 <label class="analysis-label" for="analysis">Analyte:</label>
     <select class="analysis" id="analysis" name="analysis" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
    <option>Select</option>
           <option value = "TN">TN</option>
           <option value = "TP,NO2+3">TP,NO2+3</option>
           </select>
      <label class="preserve-label" for="preserve">Preserved</label>
      <select class="select_preserve" id="preserve" name="preserve" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
        <option>Select</option>
           <option value = "HNO3">HNO&#8323;</option>
           <option value = "H2SO4">H&#8322;SO&#8324;</option>
    </select>
     <label class="cool-label" for="cool">Cooled</label>
    <select class="select_cool" id="cool" name="cool" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">  
        <option>Select</option>
           <option value = "Ice">Ice</option>
           <option value = "Frozen">Frozen</option>
           <option value = "None">None</option>
        </select>  
  </div>  <!--Fieldblank-->
  </fieldset>   <!--Fieldblank -->
 <hr /><span id="writeroot"></span> 
   </div>     <!--duplicate template-->
  </fieldset>   <!--duplicate template-->


 <button type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="moreFields" onclick="moreFields()">ADD FIELD BLANK</button>
 <button type="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="plus" id="add_FieldDup">ADD FIELD DUP</button>
```

I got the duplicate to work (when the field blank wasn't hidden) but I cannot get the field blank to work. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should extract your javascript from your dom, put it in separate js and make function work in any of this blocks, create class="template" block and inside give any needed interaction buttons and inputs classes so there can exist multiple parent elements with same inside structure... then cloning does not get in a way of your interaction logic.

In js go like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".template .interaction_button_one").on('click', function(){
    //... here you go traversing like
    $(this).parents('.template').find('.some_important_div').show();
})
});
```

Notice .on(), this is delegation, and it will give same interaction bindings to all of your elements.